# Would it be possible to port picoc to javascript with emscripten?

Tags: c, emscripten, picoc

I don't see how this would be possible, because it would require an input and output stream, which would be possible through node, but that's not really what I'm trying to do.

I just need to execute simple code and get an output in a browser.

I was thinking emscripten could help me do this, but I just don't see how.

Could someone please shed some light on this subject for me?

Comment: Emscripten does provide standard input/output streams via overridable callback functions.

Comment: What kind of input/output do you need that you are concerned about working?  In principle I don't see why compiling with emscripten would be a problem.